# Flutter Project - Testing Universal Link from a production app to a Dev or even TestFlight app not working, But Dev to Dev is working just fine

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, ios-universal-links

I don't really know if this is the issue.

1. I have a test app that used the exact URL that the production app has
2. From the test app everything is working great (dev provisioning profile to dev profile)
3. From the Production app I can't seem to open the link, it fails always.
4. my initial thought was that the provisioning is wrong and I have to upload to TestFlight to get a production profile but this also didn't work.
5. so I wonder what might this be. why when calling for the test app everything is working and the production it is not?
6. I don't have access to the code in the production app, It is not mine. But the developers over there sent me the code for the test app as a reference to the code they are using.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     var myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 250, height: 100))
     myButton.setTitle("Tap to open link", for: .normal)
     myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
     self.view .addSubview(myButton)
   }

   @objc
   func buttonTapped(sender: Any) {
       let domainLink = "https://dynamic-link.ourDomain.com/?lat=37.718&lon=-110.591&partner=partner"

    if let url = URL(string: domainLink) {

        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [.universalLinksOnly: true]) { (success) in
            if !success {
                // not a universal link or app not installed
                let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
                safariViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
                self.present(safariViewController, animated: true)
                }
        }}
   }
   ```

The AASA files are in place or it wouldn't work for the test app also... This is working.
The only thing I can think about it something with provisioning but I can't put my finger on it. OR in other words, Can I open an app that wasn't downloaded from the AppStore from and app that did come from the AppStore? If not then this solves everything.

[image]

As you can see I have one entitlement file for debug and production

Any ideas? I'm really lost here.
10x

Comment: There is an app in the App Store, Third party that is in production already. The have a button in the app that does exactly what the code I showed does. My App is in TestFlight, Not in production Yet. I'm trying to test from a test app and everything is working. When testing from that app that is in production (The store) success is false so it is opening the safaiVC with my website but not my app

Comment: in those entitlements files, do you have the same associated domains values in all files?

Comment: Yes Lucho. It is exactly the same file for all of the schemas as I showed on the image I've added

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have two entitlements files, one for debug and one for production. When this happened to me, the production one was missing the associated domains values.

Comment: I dont thing it is the provisioning as like in your case (Maybe but not sure) ... how do I check this? But the issue is that when calling the Code I showed from a test app the is in dev mode to my app everything is working and my app is opening but when clicking on the button the that production app than the success is false and it fails... My app is still in dev or (TestFlight) in both cases so my provisioning profile doesn't change at all at this point I think

Comment: @Erez He is not talking about certificate. In your project you have set associate domain inside the capability section. When you set domain it will automatically added in . entitlement file. So it might be possible that this file only set for debug mode. For checking go to project build setting and select all and then in search bar type . entitlements So you can get path of this file and check, this file path is added for both mode debug and production.

Comment: @RajaKishan for my project (Flutter project) all of them are Runner/Runner.entitlements. So I have them for Debug and Release... But the same one for all of them

Comment: @RajaKishan, But one thing that I do say for sure that that I was in debug mode and it didn't work also for the production app but worked for the test app.... So This is the main issue... Why it is working for the test app and not for a production app (Not the app that suppose to open, That test and production are the apps that has the button that has the button that suppose to open the dynamic link, I have no control over that app )

Comment: If you’re project is built with flutter then add this point in your question description or add tags so if there is missing things for flutter environment then other flutter developer can catch it.